# Plot paired data in seaborn similar to ggpaired in R

Tags: seaborn

I am trying to create a boxplot for paired data and want to draw lines between each paired data. Something similar is possible in R using ggpaired.

Is there as way to do so using seaborn or matplotlib in python?

Thanks in advance
IB

Comment: The example using R can be viewd in this link. https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/ggpaired.html

Comment: Everything (in 2D) is possible with matplotlib, but you would need to code it yourself - no built-in function for that exists in matplotlib or seaborn.

Comment: I see. Is there an equivalent of ladder plot for paired data in matplotlib, which I can start with and then overlay the boxplots?

Comment: As said, such feature does not exist. But consider that a line between point (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) in matplotlib is simply `ax.plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2])`, so it shouldn't be too hard to implement.

Comment: Thanks! Let me give it a try.